# Power Automate not pulling through correct measure value from Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-automate, measure

I have a power bi report that has a power automate button on it.

The power automate flow does a few things but ends up making a http response.

The issue I am having is that I need to use a measure from the report called 'ValidForm_PA' this basically checks that enough slicers have been selected and returns 'Ready' or 'Not_Ready' strings, I use this in the power automate report to decide if to do the http post or not as the form is not valid, e.g. the PBI selections.

On my PBI report the measure shows as...

[image]

'Not_Ready'

But when it comes through to the power automate it shows as 'Ready'...

[image]

Pulling my hair out, any ideas?